# NSDate convert NSDateComponents issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatecomponents

The results of destinationDate and components differ.
how do i solve this problem?

```
NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone      = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSDate* sourceDate              = [NSDate date];
NSInteger sourceGMTOffset       = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset  = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval interval         = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

NSDate* destinationDate         = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate];

NSCalendar *calendar            = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components    = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit  |
                                                        NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                                                        NSDayCalendarUnit   |
                                                        NSHourCalendarUnit  |
                                                        NSMinuteCalendarUnit|
                                                        NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:destinationDate];

NSLog(@"%@", destinationDate); 
NSLog(@"%@", components);
```

2013-04-24 19:27:09 +0000

Calendar Year: 2013
    Month: 4
    Leap month: no
    Day: 25
    Hour: 4
    Minute: 27
    Second: 9

Comment: What is your problem here, description of date will be always in GMT.  Its seems like your localTimeZone is 5 hours behind GMT. First log can be interpreted as 4:27 PM, it is the same shown in components

Comment: have you got the answer.

Comment: I'm struggling with a close issue, but I can't understand from your code what were you trying to achieve on the first place - could you please state this with few preliminary words?

Answer (score 5):

The date (`destinationDate`) is printed in GMT. However, the date components are not because the calendar is created with the local time zone.

If you try it with `calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]` you will get the same result from both. Otherwise you'll get the difference added twice (first time by your code,  second time by the calendar)

Actually, your code doesn't make a lot of sense. `NSDate` should never be modified by time zone because it doesn't hold any time zone information. A `NSDate` always represents a specific moment in time, independent on time zones. Transform the date only if you want to convert it to a string - and when you do, use `NSCalendar` or `NSDateFormatter` with the correct time zone set.

The following code is enough to print out the date with the system (default) time zone,

```
NSDate* sourceDate              = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar            = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit  |
                                                     NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                                                     NSDayCalendarUnit   |
                                                     NSHourCalendarUnit  |
                                                     NSMinuteCalendarUnit|
                                                     NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:destinationDate];

NSLog(@"%@", sourceDate); 
NSLog(@"%@", components);
```

Comment: could you please add to your explanation where the system timezone is (implicitly) applied? is it in the calendar? in the transformation to components? you only state you want a Gregorian calendar, you say nothing about time-zone...

Comment: @MottiShneor This is a very old answer and improved the wording a bit. The system timezone is stored in the calendar. It is used when you want to convert `Date`(a moment in time) to specific time components (relative to given timezone).

Answer (score 1):

`NSDateComponents` always gives the date in the form of GMT so simply place like below you'l get the current date.

```
NSDateComponents *components    = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit  |
                                                            NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                                                            NSDayCalendarUnit   |
                                                            NSHourCalendarUnit  |
                                                            NSMinuteCalendarUnit|
                                                            NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

replace `destinationDate` with `[NSDate date]` .

output:

```
 2013-04-24 16:05:08 +0000

<NSDateComponents: 0x7e3e5b0>
    Calendar Year: 2013
    Month: 4
    Day: 24
    Hour: 16
    Minute: 5
    Second: 8
```

Comment: How did you conclude what OP wants?

Comment: he mensioned that destinationDate and components differ that's why i find out the problem in his code .

Comment: In his code he is creating a sourceDate as currentDate and using the interval to create a destinationDate which depending on the timeZone will be advanced or delayed. The question itself is very vague and why did you say to replace destinationDate with currentDate. Very confusing.